# How to change the desktop wallpaper by a program of .NET?

Tags: .net, winapi

Is there some windows APIs that change the desktop wall paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this
http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19517-change-wallpaper-using-vb-net.aspx